# How to look for a substring GQL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, gql

I'm trying to stop duplicates of a database entity called "Post" in my program. In order to do this I want to append a number like "1" or "2" next to it. In other words:

`helloworld`
`helloworld1`
`helloworld2`

In order to do this I need to query the database for `postid`'s starting with `helloworld`. I read that GQL doesn't support the `LIKE` operation, so what can I do instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Every datastore entity has an unique key. So what is the problem? If you do not assign a key yousef, the datastore will provide one (id).

Answer (score 0):

Could you make the number a separate field?  Then you won't have to search for prefix.

Comment: Yes, but on what condition would I increment the number?

Comment: You could use a [Counter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) or encode both fields into the key and query for highest entry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no LIKE.

Based on your criteria the closest you can achieve will be a query using the '>' and '<' operators.

```
select * from Post where postid > "helloworld" and postid < "helloworld9999" for instance.
```

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, so there may well be a better approach, maybe you can elaborate your use case.